# Agrupar resultados MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estoy generando un JSON en donde segun una consulta quiero que me traiga de una tabla los campos "resistencia" relacionados con el campo "fecha_entrega", pero me los regresa separados cuando quiero que los traiga agrupados por el campo "fecha_entrega".

Este es el codigo:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(fecha_entrega)";
$sql.=" FROM registros where sem_entrega = ".date("W")." ORDER BY fecha_entrega";
$query=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die("ajax-grid-data.php: get PO");
$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
$nestedData=array(); 
$nestedData["fecha"] = $row["fecha_entrega"];
$sqlr = "SELECT DISTINCT(resistencia) FROM registros WHERE fecha_entrega = '".$row["fecha_entrega"]."' ORDER BY resistencia";
$queryr=mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlr) or die("ajax-grid-data.php: get PO");
while( $rowr=mysqli_fetch_array($queryr) ) {
    $nestedData["res"] = $rowr["resistencia"];

    $data[] = $nestedData;
}
}
$json_data = array("data" => $data);
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Este es el JSON que me regresa:

```
{
data: [
    {
       fecha: "2019-04-01",
       res: "100"
    },
    {
       fecha: "2019-04-02",
       res: "200"
    },
    {
       fecha: "2019-04-03",
       res: "50"
    },
    {
       fecha: "2019-04-03",
       res: "150"
    },
    {
       fecha: "2019-04-03",
       res: "200"
     }
  ]
}
```

Cuando estoy intentando que me lo regrese asi:

```
{
data: [
    {
       fecha: "2019-04-01",
       res: "100"
    },
    {
       fecha: "2019-04-02",
       res: "200"
    },
    {
       fecha: "2019-04-03",
       res: "50",
       res: "150",
       res: "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Para  hacerlo por PHP vas a tener que programar una lógica en la lectura de los datos para que vaya agrupando al modo que muestras, o bien manipular el array una vez creado para que agrupe esos valores por fecha. Todo eso es posible, si quieres que te ayudemos debes mostrar en ese caso cómo queda el array en sí y cómo quisieras que quede. Si fuera tú, traería mis datos agrupados en la consultas simplemente. En MySQL existe por ejemplo `GROUP_CONCAT`, si agrupas por fecha, los valores de `res` vendrían en una sola columna por cada fecha con un separador, algo así: `50|150|200`

Comment: Alguna vez haz usado `Collections` con php, te dejo el link puede que te funcione. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections